# Rspec failure for relationships controller, Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to make a spec for my relationships controller and have a failure for the #create method (Couldn't find User with 'id'=).
Can you please tell me how to fix this?
Thanks for your help, if you have any question please ask. :)

relationships_controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

relationships_controller_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe RelationshipsController do
  let(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    sign_in :user, create(:user)
  end


  describe '#create' do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }
    it "should require logged-in user to create relationship" do
      post :create, followed_id: user.id
      expect{
        Relationship.create
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end


  describe '#create' do
    let!(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }

    it "should require logged-in user to destroy relationship" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: relationship.id
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Failure:

```
RelationshipsController
  #create
    should require logged-in user to destroy relationship
  #create
    should require logged-in user to create relationship (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) RelationshipsController#create should require logged-in user to create relationship
     Failure/Error:
       expect{
         Relationship.create
       }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)

       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

relationship:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Associations
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

#Validations
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Associations
      has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                      foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                      dependent:   :destroy
      has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                      foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                      dependent:   :destroy
      has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
      has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

      # Follows a user.
      def follow(other_user)
        active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
      end
    end
```

Comment: You've not posted the `followed_id` parameter

Comment: I mean in your controller spec, when you make a post request

Comment: Also, it looks like your expectation is manually creating a relationship then checking the count.  This isn't actually testing your controller.

Comment: @AaronWashburn could you please explain your comment, maybe with an example or tutorial. thanks

Comment: @Jony, you are calling Relationship.create then checking to see if a relationship is created.  This is testing your model, not your controller.  If you look at the destroy spec, you are using the destroy controller action directly to change the relationship count. You want to do the same thing for your create action.  Then, don't forget to name your test descriptions correctly so others can tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked out :

```
  describe '#create' do
    let!(:followed) { create(:user) }
    it "should require logged-in user to create relationship" do
      expect{
        post :create, followed_id: followed.id
      }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

pass `:followed_id` in spec and run it again

```
describe '#create' do
it "should require logged-in user to create relationship" do
  post :create, followed_id: user.id
  expect{
    Relationship.create
  }.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

In your test -

```
describe RelationshipsController do
  let(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
```

user is not being created until need.

```
describe RelationshipsController do
  let(:relationship) { create(:relationship) }
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
```

Using the ! operator forces the user variable to be created and stored to the database.  Otherwise the variable is lazy-loaded (only when needed).  That's why it isn't available in the database